# Delete google sheet/tab script not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this delete sheet script that i'm trying to incorporate to my sheet and I would appreciate all the help I can to get this working.

Here comes a description on:

1. How I want it to work
2. What actually works
3. What don't work
4. What has been done so far to solve the problem

**How I want it to work**

So I have a sheet that is called "Pipe" and that is where I have all my prospects. When a meeting is about to get executed I will then put in today's date in Col M on that sheet.

When that happens it will then make a copy of my tab called Meeting Template and name it after the company I am having a meeting with. It will also create an array in the Dashboard sheet that watches a row (A1-I1) in the newly created tab.

When I close or lose a deal or the deal gets old I then want the affected sheet to be deleted.

**What actually works**

- Creating a meeting template when the date gets put in Col M with the company name (Works)
- Creating array in the dashboard template the watches the newly created sheet (Works)

**What don't work**

Deleting the sheet when a deal is won, lost or gets old.

**What has been done so far to solve the problem**

I found this script that watches an overview sheet "just like my dashboard" and it watches for old dates in it and when it finds old dates it deletes the sheet with the same name in that row and after that delete the row.

This script suits my need pretty good, so I have this drop down menu in my meeting template with the options "won" or "lost" and if I choose for example "won" it will then add -days to the cell "I1" so it will be a past date and trigger the script to delete the sheet.

But I can't figure out how to make it work on my sheet.

Here is the script:

```js
function deleteOldRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();
  var currentDate = new Date();//today
  var monthOld = Date.now() - 30*24*3600*1000; 
  for (i=lastrow;i>=1;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][10];
values[0] 
if ((tempDate!=NaN) && (tempDate <= (monthOld))) {
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
  var deleteSheet = ss.getSheetByName(values[i-1][10]); // Added. Or ss.getSheetByName(values[i-1][1].trim());
  if (deleteSheet) ss.deleteSheet(deleteSheet); // Added
}

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Here the link to my sample sheet with the all the code in it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBM-fpRYu8Xw_FiXfb03jTAn1_FRnDW2lkSHGH7AmTk/edit?usp=sharing